# Token invalid Travian when call from curl

Tags: php, curl

I try to Exchange silver to gold but i got error message:

```
{"response": {"error":true,"errorMsg":"Token invalid","data":[]}}
```

The token is right but i don't know way this error can you help me to fixed

```
$url ='http://ts1.travian.com/dorf1.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$dir  . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match("/ajaxToken = '(.*?)'/s", $response, $s3);
$url ='http://ts1.travian.com/ajax.php?cmd=silverExchange';
$data = array('cmd'=>'silverExchange','exTyp'=>'SilverToGold','s' =>'200','g'=>'1','ajaxToken'=>$s3[1]);                                                
$data_json = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Not everybody have played Travian. We don't quite know how Travian servers handle http requests. Perhaps, you could elaborate more or provide some documentation from Travian REST API if there exists.

Comment: i can't add API because Token is change when post or login you can try in any server you like